# Grouping the results from a view

Tags: views, 8, search

I have created the view of indexed fields of custom entity products where I have data from various vendors like Amazon, Flipkart, Ebay. For indexing, I have used search_api module (database search). When I am searching data through it, It shows me data like this-

**Amazon**

Product 1

Product 2

Product 3

**Ebay**

Product x

Product y

Product z

**Flipkart**

Product a

Product b

Product c

But, I want products to be listed side by side in the form of -

**Amazon** **Ebay** **Flipkart**

Product 1  Product x  Product a

Product 2  Product y  Product b

Product 3  Product z  Product c

Is there any way to show the grouping results in the above form through table?

Comment: Do you really want/need a table to display the results? Or would placing the columns using CSS also be sufficient (e.g., using your themes grid system or doing it manually using the CSS `float` rule)?

Comment: Table is more better to display results as vendors can be 'n' numbers so manually defining template isn't possible

Comment: Anyone, please help me out here?